# Importing a certificate into Jetty

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, jetty, keytool

The overall goal here is to have jetty be configured with a client certificate to be able to call a secure SOAP web service.

Does anyone know how to configure Jetty to accept a client certificate (*.cer) ?

**Update**: I did not find an easy way to implement a solution to my problem/question, but the sole answer here technically is correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetty can also use [JK](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/), so you could easily set up your certificate in Apache instead, to serve any https requests through it... More info [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Apache).

If you really want to setup Jetty for SSL, then [here's the info](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html).